# Como receber valor de querystring numa action?

Tags: c#, asp-net-core, querystring

Estou criando uma API com ASP.NET Core e gostaria de saber como faço para fazer uma pesquisa via *querystring*, no caso, a URL vir algo como `/api/programas?nome=teste`

Como eu faria na minha controller?

Exemplo da minha controller, neste caso filtrando por ID (só um exemplo mostrando como estou fazendo meu endpoint):

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult<AppResponse>> GetAsync(Guid id)
{
    var app = await _programaHandle.GetAsync(id);
                     
    return Ok(app);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível declarar um parâmetro na *action* e usar o atributo `FromQuery`.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<AppResponse>> GetAsync(Guid id, [FromQuery] string nome)
{
    var app = await _programaHandle.GetAsync(id);                 
    return Ok(app);
}
```

Comment: blz, só uma outra duvida, se for varios filtros, tipo -> /api/programas?nome=teste&&categoria=teste&&aplicativo=teste, eu preciso passar - > [FromQuery] string nome, string aplicativo, string categoria, ou existe uma forma de receber 1 parametro ja pra tudo, no caso uma classe...

Comment: pq isso vai ser opcional, a pessoa vai poder passar 1 filtro, 2 filtros, 3 filtros, quantos ela quiser...

Comment: @Desalex Você pode criar uma classe com todas as propriedades e pedir uma instância dela como parâmetro da ação. Neste caso, usa o `FromQuery` somente no parâmetro mesmo.

Comment: só pra exemplificar, supondo que eu tenha uma classe AppResponse, eu passaria [FromQuery] AppResponse response, ou somente AppResponse response??

Comment: Primeira opção.